# How to solve "returns a value referencing data owned by the current function" error in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to code a binary tree that generates random expressions. I need random numbers and a set of functions. I receive a vector with the functions and the depth for the expression in the tree. In the operators vector, I also include a "ELEM" string, this is used to choose a random element from the vector and then change it for a float.

It seems I still do not understand the exact use for borrows, moving and ownership, since it is a recursive function, it shows the error saying that value has been borrowed and cannot return a local variable.

```
use rand::Rng;

struct Expression_Node<'a> {
    val: &'a str,
    left: Option<Box<Expression_Node<'a>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Expression_Node<'a>>>,
}

fn Create_Expression(
    operators: Vec<&str>,
    p: i32,
) -> std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<Expression_Node<'_>>> {
    if p == 0 {
        let value = String::from(rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>().to_string());
        let value2: &str = value.as_ref();
        //println!("{:?}", value);
        let new_node = Expression_Node {
            val: value2,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        };
        return Some(Box::new(new_node));
    }
    let value: &str = *rand::thread_rng().choose(&operators).unwrap();
    println!("VAL: {:?}", value);
    if value == "ELEM" {
        let value = rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>().to_string();
    }

    let new_node = Expression_Node {
        val: value,
        left: Create_Expression(operators.clone(), p - 1),
        right: Create_Expression(operators.clone(), p - 1),
    };
    return Some(Box::new(new_node));
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `value`
  --> src/lib.rs:22:16
   |
15 |         let value2: &str = value.as_ref();
   |                            ----- `value` is borrowed here
...
22 |         return Some(Box::new(new_node));
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Comment: The randomly generated value needs to outlive function body. May be store owned string in the expression instead of slice?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `ExpressionNode` and `create_expression` instead, please.

Comment: There is no reason to use `std::option::Option` or `std::boxed::Box` — these are in the prelude and don't need to be fully qualified (and indeed you didn't qualify them everywhere). Using an explicit `return` at the end of a block is also non-idiomatic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The biggest problem with the code is the use of `&str` in the `ExpressionNode`.
The simplest fix is to change it to `String`. You can see the fix for that below.
This also allows removal of all the lifetime annotations.

There's also a second fix in that code that is important.

```
let value: &str = *rand::thread_rng().choose(&operators).unwrap();
if value == "ELEM"{
    let value = rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>().to_string();
}
```

should be updating `value`, so the assignment within the if should not contain `let`, and the first assignment should be `let mut value`.

If you're not happy with all the assignments that are happening when switching to a `String`, you have two other options - use a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) string or use a enum for the contained value type so that it can contain a string or a float, something like - `val: Either<&str, f64>` (There's a version using this at the end of this answer).

The string based version:

```
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ExpressionNode {
    val: String,
    left: Option<Box<ExpressionNode>>,
    right: Option<Box<ExpressionNode>>,
}

fn create_expression(operators: &[&str], p: i32) -> Option<Box<ExpressionNode>> {
    if p == 0 {
        let value = String::from(rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>().to_string());
        let new_node = ExpressionNode {
            val: value,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        };
        return Some(Box::new(new_node));
    }
    let mut value = rand::thread_rng().choose(&operators).unwrap().to_string();
    if value == "ELEM" {
        value = rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>().to_string();
    }

    let new_node = ExpressionNode {
        val: value,
        left: create_expression(operators.clone(), p - 1),
        right: create_expression(operators.clone(), p - 1),
    };
    Some(Box::new(new_node))
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["a", "b", "c", "ELEM"];
    let tree = create_expression(&v, 3);
    println!("tree = {:?}", tree)
}
```

For comparison, here's a version using `Either<&str, f64>`:

```
use either::Either;
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ExpressionNode<'a> {
    val: Either<&'a str, f64>,
    left: Option<Box<ExpressionNode<'a>>>,
    right: Option<Box<ExpressionNode<'a>>>,
}

fn create_expression<'a>(operators: &[&'a str], p: i32) -> Option<Box<ExpressionNode<'a>>> {
    if p == 0 {
        let value = rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>();
        let new_node = ExpressionNode {
            val: Either::Right(value),
            left: None,
            right: None,
        };
        return Some(Box::new(new_node));
    }
    let v = *rand::thread_rng().choose(&operators).unwrap();
    let value = if v == "ELEM" {
        Either::Right(rand::thread_rng().gen::<f64>())
    } else {
        Either::Left(v)
    };

    let new_node = ExpressionNode {
        val: value,
        left: create_expression(operators.clone(), p - 1),
        right: create_expression(operators.clone(), p - 1),
    };
    Some(Box::new(new_node))
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["a", "b", "c", "ELEM"];
    let tree = create_expression(&v, 3);
    println!("tree = {:?}", tree)
}
```